# Perform SVM on images

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, imread

```
from scipy.misc import imread
from sklearn import svm

X_train = []
y_train = []

def f(dir, value):
    files = listdir(dir)
    for file in files:
        image_data = imread(dir + file)
        X_train.append(image_data)
        y_train.append(value)


f('data1/', 0)
f('data2/', 1)

model = svm.SVC().fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I'm trying to use SVM to predict if a given picture belongs to data1 or data2.

When i run the above code, i got an error `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` Is this due to the images being different sizes? If so how can i crop, say, 50 px from the centre of the image?

Comment: Yes, equal dimensions are needed. And you probably want to resize, not crop. Often it's also not recommended to work on raw images, but some preprocessed low-dimensional embedding (blur, black/white, PCA). Apart from that, depending on the exact task, a more specialized feature-enmbedding might be needed to give SVMs chances to work (Gabor-filters, SURF, NN-based feature-extraction)

Comment: Please also note that the `imread()` with default params will read the single image as a 3-d data array (for width, height and channel) and that makes your `X_train` a 4-d data object, whereas the sklearn estimators will work on 2-d data only (one for sample, and other for features) so you will need to flatten the 3-d image data into a 1-d array which becomes the row of `X_train`.